# $asyncValidators with params for two modes ('new' and 'edit' form)

Tags: angularjs

I'm using $asyncValidators to check if email is available or not. 
I have only one controller and template for two modes : 'new' and 'edit'.
i created a directive for this check. But on 'edit' mode, i don't want to check current email. So, in my controller, i've created $scope.initialEmail to compare it with entered email. But i don't know how to use it in directive (for edit mode).

Template :

```
 <input id="email" name="email" type="email" class="form-control" 
 placeholder="{{'placeholders_email'|i18n}}" 
 ng-model="user.email" ng-required="true" email-available/>

 <ng-messages for="myForm.email.$error" ng-if="myForm.email.$dirty">
 <ng-message class="red" when="emailAvailable">{{'email_exists_in_db'|i18n}}</ng-message>
 ...
```

Controller :

```
 //formMode is injected in controller ('new' or 'edit')
 $scope.formMode = angular.copy(formMode); 
 $scope.user = {email: '...', ...};
 switch(formMode){
     case 'edit':
          $scope.initialEmail = angular.copy($scope.user.email);
          break;
 }
```

Factory :

```
 //AuthHttp is an auth service using $http
 angular.module('myapp').factory('EmailAvailableValidator', ['$q', 'AuthHttp', function($q, AuthHttp) {
return function(email) {        
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    AuthHttp.get('/rest/users/emailAvailable/'+email).then(function() {
        deferred.resolve();
    }, function() {
        deferred.reject();
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}}]);
```

Directive :

```
 angular.module('myapp').directive('emailAvailable', ['EmailAvailableValidator', function(EmailAvailableValidator) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            switch(scope.formMode){
                case 'new':
                    ngModel.$asyncValidators.emailAvailable = EmailAvailableValidator;
                    break;
                case 'edit':
                    ngModel.$asyncValidators.emailAvailable = function(email){ // ?
                        if(!_.isEqual(scope.initialEmail, ngModel.$modelValue)){ // ?
                            return EmailAvailableValidator; // ??
                        }
                    };
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Comment: in other words, how can i use $asyncValidators with conditions ?

Comment: The async validator is executed only one time. On edit mode, i want to compare current value with initial value, and the current value may change while filling the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add $q.when for the edit mode like this :

Factory :

```
  angular.module('myapp').factory('UsersService', ['AuthHttp', '$q', function (AuthHttp, $q) {
    return {

        emailAvailable: function(email){
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            AuthHttp.get('/rest/users/emailAvailable/'+email).then(function() {
                deferred.resolve();
            }, function() {
                deferred.reject();
            });
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
}]);
```

Directive :

```
angular.module('myapp').directive('emailAvailable', ['UsersService', '$q',  function(UsersService, $q) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require : 'ngModel',
        link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            switch(scope.formMode){
                case 'new':
                    ngModel.$asyncValidators.emailAvailable = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
                        return UsersService.emailAvailable(modelValue || viewValue);
                    };
                    break;
                case 'edit':
                    ngModel.$asyncValidators.emailAvailable = function(modelValue, viewValue){
                        var newValue = modelValue || viewValue;
                        var promise;
                        if(!_.isEqual(scope.initialEmail, newValue)){
                            promise = UsersService.emailAvailable(newValue);
                        } else {
                            promise = $q.when(!_.isEqual(scope.initialEmail, newValue));
                        }
                        return promise;
                    };
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```